# Get string with listGetAt delimiter

Tags: string, coldfusion, delimiter

I have this string `supplier_id ~|(~ '3422' ~)|~supplier_name ~|(~ 'WD Ltd.' ~)|~project_personnel ~|(~ 'Yaya Toure (temp)' ~)|~lt_project_code ~|(~ '013-7718321' ~)|~ id ~|(~ '668'`

and I need to get content inside `~|(~data~)|~`. I use `listGetAt` with delimiter. The problem is some data inside delimiter contain bracket `(` which ruin the search. For example with `Yaya Toure (temp)` that contain bracket.

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset test = "supplier_id ~|(~ '3422' ~)|~supplier_name ~|(~ 'WD Ltd.' ~)|~project_personnel ~|(~ 'Yaya Toure (temp)' ~)|~lt_project_code ~|(~ '013-7718321' ~)|~ id ~|(~ '668'">

#test#
<cfset count_column = ListLen(test, "~)|~")>

<cfset column_name = ''>
<cfloop index="i" from="1" to=8 >
    <cfif i mod 2 EQ 0>
        <cfset column_name = ListAppend(column_name,listGetAt(test, i, "~|(~~)|~" ),",")>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>

<br>
<br>

Result : #column_name#
</cfoutput>
```

Output : `Result : '3422' , 'WD Ltd.' , 'Yaya Toure ,'`

My expected result is : `'3422' , 'WD Ltd.' , 'Yaya Toure (temp)' , '013-7718321'`. It will work if I removed `(temp)` from the string. Please assist me with this and thanks in advance.

iddle : https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=ab77d723-1b04-46d6-8d80-fb765b881768/5c8c9eed-a16a-4f3a-b40b-fd7479fdc5ea/dae87d17-2826-4c63-b54c-55a57a8e4398.cfm

Comment: You would probably have more luck using regular expressions for this.

Comment: regex : https://cffiddle.org/app/file?filepath=e4ae911f-9bdc-46d0-96c5-45d7e997dde2/9ad61070-9204-4789-bcf3-9ae79d9b2441/f83ee922-8a38-4411-9dc8-1ef37699f04d.cfm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Option 1:** Use a CF list function that supports multi-character delimiters, like [listToArray](https://cfdocs.org/listtoarray).

```
<cfscript>
    // split on first delimiter get "name->value" string
    nameValuePairs = test.listToArray("~)|~" , false, true);

    columnValues = [];
    nameValuePairs.each(function(pair, index) {
        // split on second delimiter to extract value
        local.data = pair.listToArray("~|(~", false, true);
        columnValues.append( local.data[ 2 ] );
    });
    
    writeDump( "Result 1: "& columnValues.toList() );    
</cfscript>
```

**Option 2:** If you can identify a single character that's never present within the values, perhaps a non-printable character, just replace the existing delimiters, and loop as usual.

```
<cfscript>
      // 31 == Unit separator        
      delim     = chr(31);
      newString = test.replace( "~)|~", delim, "all")
                    .replace( "~|(~", delim, "all");

      columnValues = [];
      newString.listToArray( delim ).each(function( elem, index) {
          if (index mod 2 == 0) {
              columnValues.append( elem );
          }
      });
    
      WriteOutput( "<br>Result 2: "&  columnValues.toList()  );        
</cfscript>
```

[TryCF Examples](https://trycf.com/gist/0704f6eb2c908af3cb87e2cf246fffa8/acf2021?theme=monokai)

### Update

> problem though for this string `supp~|(~lier_isd ~|(~ '3422' ~)|~supplier_name ~|(~ 'WD Ltd.' ~)|~project_personnel ~|(~ 'Yaya Toure (temp)' ~)|~lt_project_code ~|(~ '013-7718321' ~)|~ id ~|(~ '668'` I was expecting `lier_isd ~|(~ '3422', 'WD Ltd.', 'Yaya Toure (temp)', '013-7718321'`

The initial string appeared to use the format `name ~|(~ value ~)|~`. However, if the *value* itself can contain one of the list delimiters  `~|(~`, you won't be able to use list functions, because the function can't differentiate between when `~|(~` is acting as a delimiter and when it's part of a value. You'll need to use a regex instead. That's not my forte, but something like this should work

[TryCF Example](https://trycf.com/gist/2dfca5f01537ed074c66d4a7f9c00603/acf2021?theme=monokai)

```
  values = [];
  // Find groups of "~|(~ value ~)|~"
  matches = reMatch( "~\|\(~(.+?)(?=~\)\|~)", test);
  matches.each( function(item, index) {
    // remove text up to and including the first "~|(~"
    local.str = reReplace( item, ".*?~\|\(~", "");
    values.append( local.str );
  });
  
  WriteOutput( "Result 1: "& values.toList() );
```

**Explanation**

```
     ~        Find tilde "~"
     \|       Find pipe "|"
     \(       Find open parenthesis "("
     ~        Find tilde "~"
     
     (.+?)    One ore more characters, non-greedy
     
     (?=      Followed by (Non-capturing lookahead) 
     ~        tilde "~"
     \)       close parenthesis "("
     \|       pipe "|"
     ~        tilde "~"
     )        End lookahead
     
     .*?      Zero or more characters
     ~        Find tilde "~"
     \|       Find pipe "|"
     \(       Find open parenthesis "("
     ~        Find tilde "~"
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and example. I appreciated it. Thanks

Comment: problem though for this string `"supp~|(~lier_isd ~|(~ '3422' ~)|~supplier_name ~|(~ 'WD Ltd.' ~)|~project_personnel ~|(~ 'Yaya Toure (temp)' ~)|~lt_project_code ~|(~ '013-7718321' ~)|~ id ~|(~ '668'"` . I was expecting `lier_isd ~|(~ '3422', 'WD Ltd.', 'Yaya Toure (temp)', '013-7718321'`

Comment: It is because that string has a different format. The delimiters for the first name/value are incorrect. It should be `supp~|(~lier_isd~)|~`. Was that a typo? Also, are you deliberately excluding the "id" value `'668'`?

Comment: The invalid format issue still needs to be addressed, but if you only want the first 4 values, add an `if` condition https://trycf.com/gist/9ef9969be44881ac3157f4d03b07332b/acf2021?theme=monokai

Comment: It's not a typo. `lier_isd ~|(~ '3422' ` is in `~|(~ value ~)|~` delimiter.

Comment: I leave out `688` because it's not in `~|(~ value ~)|~` delimiter.

Comment: But the value itself contains one of the list delimiters `~|(~`. You won't be able to use list functions, because the function can't differentiate between when it's acting as a delimiter and when it's part of a value. You'll need to a regex instead. That's not my forte, but something like this should work https://trycf.com/gist/2dfca5f01537ed074c66d4a7f9c00603/acf2021?theme=monokai

Comment: love the explanation! thank you very much